# Errors logged on console during AWS CloudWatch publicly Shared dashboard load

Tags: amazon-web-services, iframe, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, http-status-code-403

When I tried to access publicly shared dashboard it gives following errors on console during graph load:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
> POST https://cloudwatch.amazonaws.com/cloudwatch/CloudWatch/data/auth.V4BatchSign/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 403(Forbidden)

[image: Console Error]
I just want to load CloudWatch shared dashboard on `iframe` without any console error.

For that I have updated the IAM role of publicly shared dashboards by granting CloudWatch full read or list access.